# Having trouble parsing HTML with PHP and Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, scrape

I am in the process of trying to parse HTML with simple_html_dom.php.  The HTML I am trying to parse is shown below.  I can successfully grab each product name: `Product 1`, `Product 2`, `Product 3`, etc.

I would also like to grab the `itemprice_0` from each product. This is where I am running into issues. Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://www.webaddress.com');

foreach($html->find('span.productName') as $e)
echo $e.'<br />'; //successfully displays all product names

foreach($html->find('#itemprice_0') as $e)
echo $e; //doesn't display the item prices

foreach($html->find('.dollar') as $e)
echo $e; //doesn't display the dollar amounts
?>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<span class="productName">Product 1</span>  

<p class="price">
<strike>
<span class="dollar-symbol">$</span>  
<span class="dollar">15</span><span class="dot">.</span>  
<span class="cents">99</span></strike>
</p>  

<p class="salePrice" id='itemprice_0'>  
<span class="dollar-symbol">$</span>  
<span class="dollar">13</span><span class="dot">.</span>  
<span class="cents">99</span>  
</p>
```

Comment: I think you're missing the `innertext`. Try `echo $e->innertext;`

Comment: foreach($html->find('.salePrice') as $e)
  echo $e->children(2)->plainText;

Comment: Thank you both for providing suggestions. Both innertext and children(2)->plainText were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accessed the salePrice class and echoed out the dollar amount.

```
foreach($html->find('span.productName') as $e)
    echo $e.'<br />'; //successfully displays all product names

foreach($html->find('p.price') as $e)
    $e = str_replace(' ', '', $e);
    echo 'Regular Price: ' . $e;

foreach($html->find('p.salePrice') as $e)
    $e = str_replace(' ', '', $e);
    echo 'Sale Price: ' . $e;
```

I also removed whitespaces.

Result:

```
Product 1
Regular Price: $15.99
Sale Price: $13.99
```

I also made the loop look for the itemprice_0 id only, and got the same result:

```
foreach($html->find('p[id=itemprice_0]') as $e)
$e = str_replace(' ', '', $e);
echo 'Sale Price: ' . $e;
```

Same Result:

```
Product 1
Regular Price: $15.99
Sale Price: $13.99
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Hmmm... This is what the code returned for me (i understand there are missing line breaks):

Product 1
Regular Price: Product 1Sale Price: Product 1

Is it possible to grab the price which contains the id='itemprice_0'?

Comment: Edited my answer with the itemprice_0 id.

Answer (score 1):

`itemprice_0` is unique, if you want to select more than one element you should use class selector. In simple_html_dom you can fetch nested elements like this(didn't test it):

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

foreach($html->find('.salePrice') as $prices){
    echo $price->find('.dollor')->plaintext;
    echo $price->find('.cents')->plaintext;
}
```

Comment: itemprice_0 is not unique in this HTML.  It is located within each product, whether it is within class="price" or class="salesPrice".  What would your suggestion be for grabbing the price which contains the id="itemprice_0"?

Comment: `id` attribute always must be unique in html. could you edit your question and put the parent html element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xp=new DOMXPath($domd);
foreach($xp->query('//*[contains(@class,"dollar")]') as $e)
var_dump($e->textContent);
```